# TabHost.TabSpec setIndicator

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity, android-tabactivity

I want to get rid of the default indicator to achieve the same result when a tab is selected (no indicator). I've tried:

```
TabHost.TabSpec specs = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("").setContent(intent);
TabHost.TabSpec specs = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("",null).setContent(intent);
```

But none of this worked. How can I remove that indicator?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

```
        TabHost  tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabSpec spec;

        Intent intent;

        //Home Tab
        View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.home, null);

        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Firstclass.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("HOME").setIndicator(view1)
                .setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

In this way you can get rid of it...

Comment: Hey ,Nepster ,would you please explain what you did here?I have a question similar to this one and the only answer I got refers to a way of doing this thing in XML ,but I sort of "like" doing it programmatically and this seems to be the way ,is just that I don't really get all you are doing ,specially because I don't have acces to "getTabHost()" method.

Comment: it is now deprecated why don't you use latest http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/  but if you still want to understand this , I have created Seperate classes for each view1 inflate my home screen in view1 and then i do it for all other tab and add them as i did in home Tab.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the link ,I have been looking for something that isn't deprecated and I couldn't find much...Gonna get into the documentation now.Cheers man!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete his, try this:

```
TabHost.TabSpec specs = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setContent(intent);
TabHost.TabSpec specs = tabHost.newTabSpec("").setContent(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    tabHost = getTabHost();     
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(labelId);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void addTab(TabMainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) 
{
    Drawable indicator = mContext .getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.red_box );
    tabSpec.setIndicator(tag,indicator);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```